# Чтение из txt файла в assets

Tags: java, android-studio

Двое суток читала всё по этому поводу на Stack Overflow, но ответы все многолетней давности и указанные там способы через класс AssetManager не работают - android studio вся красная от ошибок.
Сейчас так:

```js
try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("txt.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String lines;
            while ((lines = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuffer.append(lines + "\n");
            }
            txtShow.setText(strBuffer.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Код работает, но только если txt.txt создан на виртуальном диске эмулятора.
В противном случае ошибка:

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/ru.ann.test/files/txt.txt (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Я хочу работать с эмулятором, с файлом в директории app/src/main/assets/
Как этого добиться в реалиях 2020-го года?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы открываете файл не из того места. Вы пытаетесь его в файловой системе найти, а не в `assets`.

Вот рабочий код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) для получения содержимого файла из `assets` в виде строки:

```
fun readFromAssets(context: Context, filename: String): String {
    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context.assets.open(filename), "UTF-8"))

    // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    var line: String? = reader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line) // process line
        line = reader.readLine()
    }
    reader.close()
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: Да я ещё в java далеко не спец, а тут целый Котлин :``|

Comment: @АняСтахова, по идее вам достаточно заменить в вашем коде `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);` на `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("txt.txt"))`

Comment: Да. Это сработало. Спасибо!
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("txt.txt"),"UTF-8");
Не сочтите за наглость, но ещё маленький вопрос. При сборке apk, файл txt.txt сам подцепится? Куда он должен скопироваться на телефоне?

Comment: Файл будет упакован в Apk файл

Comment: Спасибо! Значит ничего править не придётся)